# Freemarker and Spring: Add servlet path to links with @spring.url

Tags: spring, freemarker

My application uses Freemarker and Spring 3 with a servlet path that is not the root. Something like "/csm/*".

So, my URLs should be like: "http://localhost:8080/myapp/csm/*".

The problem is that when I use @spring.url (from spring.flt) it only adds "http://localhost:8080/myapp", without the servlet path "/csm/*".

Is there a way to add the servlet path to the URL as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the current HTTPServletRequest object when building your link:

```
${Request.getRequest().getServletPath()}
```

Comment: it reports: `freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression Request.getRequest is undefined`